# ReactJS - showing loading image while API call - inside Bootstrap's modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, svg

Am trying to show loading image while API call is on progress in ReactJs. Please find the below code.
    When props.loading is true, i want to show Bootstrap's modal with the spinner svg. But that spinner variable am showing where ever it is required.

Its working properly without Bootstrap's modal but, i want to show the spinner inside the bootstrap's modal.

```
render() {
     let spinner;
     if(this.props.loading != undefined )
         {
            if(this.props.loading)
                {
                    spinner = <div className="modal fade bs-example-modal-
                              sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
                          labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"> +
                                <div className="modal-dialog modal-sm" 
                          role="document"> +
                                <div className="modal-content"> +
                                <a href="#"><img src="Spinner/Spinner.svg" 
                          className="rounded mx-auto d-block" /></a> +
                                </div> +
                                </div> +
                                </div>;
                }
        }

        return
        (
            <div>
                {spinner}
            </div>
        }

    }
```

Comment: are u using react-bootstrap components or is this custom. by you?

Comment: Not custom, am using Bootstrap's 3.3.7 components.

Comment: I see. so custom, :P you are not using  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ right? because there you have a Modal component

Comment: Am using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-sizes

Answer (score 0):

You should be nullifying the spinner in the else part:

```
if(this.props.loading){
    spinner = <div className="modal fade bs-example-modal-
           sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
           labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"> +
           <div className="modal-dialog modal-sm" 
             role="document"> +
             <div className="modal-content"> +
             <a href="#"><img src="Spinner/Spinner.svg" 
             className="rounded mx-auto d-block" /></a> +
             </div> +
             </div> +
          </div>;
}else{
    spinner = null;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Actually, modal is not invoking i guess.